# Make specific Rails view show certain helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you make a specific view show a different helper.

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def about_title
        %Q{Everything you need!}.html_safe
    end

    def contact_title
        %Q{Contact us!}.html_safe
    end
end
```

I have a partial header that renders in every view but I want to show a different header title without having to edit the views directly (or edit a variable? in the view to show what I want?)

```
<h1 class="title"><%= about_title %></h1>
```

What I'm thinking is making an `if/else` in the helper but I am new to rubyonrails and I'm not sure how is this done.

Comment: Does "renders in every view" mean "in the layout template"?

Comment: I have a view named `contact.html.erb` in there i have `<%= render partial: 'internal_header' %>` which is in every other view. Inside the internal_header I have `<h1 class="title"><%= title %></h1>` what I wanted to do is declare a variable in every view to show a specific string in each view

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the title somewhere. There's a few ways you can handle this. You could use the controller + action name, and set up the titles in i18n.

```
en:
  titles:
    home_index: "Welcome!"
    session_new: "Login"
```

Then in your layout:

```
<title><%= t("titles.#{controller.controller_name}_#{controller.action_name}") %></title>
```

Another way to do it is using `content_for` & `yield` but that means putting code in your views :)